# Ploting legend with ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, tidyverse

I'm trying to plot a labeled barplot with ggplot2 with positive and negative bars.

```
indegree<- c("Volunteer work and meeting (1 code)", "TV and Video (8 codes)", "Travel by purpose (30 codes)", "Travel and unspecified time use (1 code)", "Study (1 code)",
             "Sports related activites (3 codes)", "Sports and outdoor activities (1 code)","Social life (6 codes)", "Social care(1 code)", "Shopping and services (11 codes)",
             "Second Job (2 codes)","School or University (4 codes)", "Resting-Time out (1 code)",  "Reading (4 codes)", "Radio and Music (6 codes)", "Games (9 codes)",
             "Physical exercise (20 codes)","Personal care (1 cdoe)",  "Participatory activities (4 codes)","Other personal care (3 codes)","Organisational work (4 codes)",
             "Mass media (1 code)", "Making care for textiles (5 codes)","Main job (3 codes)", "Sleep (3 codes)", "Informal help to other households  (23 codes)", "Household upkeep (7 codes)",
             "Household management (10 codes)", "Household and family care (1 code)", "Hobbies, games and computing (1 code)", "Help to an adult household member", 
             "Gardening and pet care (5 codes)", "Free time study (1 code)", "Food Management (5 codes)", "Entertainment and culture (25 codes)",  "Employment(1 code)",
             "Eating (1 code)", "Construction and repairs (8 codes)",  "Computing (10 codes)","Childcare of own household members (8 codes)", "Arts and hobbies (14 codes)", 
             "Activities related to employment (5 codes)","Punctuating activity (eg. Unspecified time use, 8 codes)")
```

Creating the indegree values

```
indegreevalues <- as.numeric(c(3, 35, 37, 26, 3, 5, 4, 36, 2, 29, 4, 23, 31, 29, 23, 28, 33, 5, 22, 37, 15, 12, 28, 28, 32, 25, 37, 26,
                                           22,4,16,30,11,34,22,5,35,26,33,26,22,16, 35))
df.1 <- data.frame(indegree, indegreevalues) #created a data frame
```

Create dataframe 2

```
outdegree<- c("Volunteer work and meeting (1 code)", "TV and Video (8 codes)", "Travel by purpose (30 codes)", "Travel and unspecified time use (1 code)", "Study (1 code)",
             "Sports related activites (3 codes)", "Sports and outdoor activities (1 code)","Social life (6 codes)", "Social care(1 code)", "Shopping and services (11 codes)",
             "Second Job (2 codes)","School or University (4 codes)", "Resting-Time out (1 code)",  "Reading (4 codes)", "Radio and Music (6 codes)", "Games (9 codes)",
             "Physical exercise (20 codes)","Personal care (1 cdoe)",  "Participatory activities (4 codes)","Other personal care (3 codes)","Organisational work (4 codes)",
             "Mass media (1 code)", "Making care for textiles (5 codes)","Main job (3 codes)", "Sleep (3 codes)", "Informal help to other households  (23 codes)", "Household upkeep (7 codes)",
             "Household management (10 codes)", "Household and family care (1 code)", "Hobbies, games and computing (1 code)", "Help to an adult household member", 
             "Gardening and pet care (5 codes)", "Free time study (1 code)", "Food Management (5 codes)", "Entertainment and culture (25 codes)",  "Employment(1 code)",
             "Eating (1 code)", "Construction and repairs (8 codes)",  "Computing (10 codes)","Childcare of own household members (8 codes)", "Arts and hobbies (14 codes)", 
             "Activities related to employment (5 codes)","Punctuating activity (eg. Unspecified time use, 8 codes)")
```

Creating outdegree

```
outdegreevalues<- as.numeric(c(30, 25, 5, 28, 22, 12, 35, 35, 30, 32, 25, 16, 34, 4, 3, 1, 24, 34, 28, 32, 19, 8, 23, 21, 30, 4, 30, 35,
                                           35,23,23,30,27,25,39,39,20,29,4,12,4,15, 5))
```

Creating a new data frame

```
df.2 <- data.frame(outdegree, outdegreevalues) #created second df
df <- merge(df.1,df.2,by.x = "indegree",by.y = "outdegree")
```

Plotting the merged data frames

```
p<-ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=indegree,y=indegreevalues),fill="blue",stat="identity",position="dodge") + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=indegree,y=-outdegreevalues),fill="red",stat="identity",position="dodge")+ 
  labs(x="Activities", y="Count", fill="") + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

However I have a problem plotting the legend. Could you help me please to plot the legend

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2yUz.png)

Comment: Could you specify what you actually want ?

Comment: @denis Could you help me please to plot the legend (blue=indegree; red=outdegree)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353396/add-legend-to-geom-bar-using-the-ggplot2-package

Comment: @MrFlick legend blue=indegree and red=outdegree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution:

```
p<-ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=indegree,y=indegreevalues,fill = "in"),stat="identity",position="dodge") + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=indegree,y=-outdegreevalues,fill = "out"),stat="identity",position="dodge")+ 
  labs(x="Activities", y="Count", fill="")+ 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
p
```

But with this you can't use `scale_color_manual` to choose the colors I think. The good practice with `ggplot` is the long format. So here with data.table for example to reshape your data:

```
library(data.table)
p<-ggplot(melt(as.data.table(df)[,outdegreevalues := -outdegreevalues],measure.vars = c("indegreevalues","outdegreevalues"))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=indegree,y=value,fill = variable),stat="identity",position="dodge") + 
  labs(x="Activities", y="Count", fill="")+ 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue"))
p
```

Comment: @user10974052 No pb. I added code to be more proper so that you can choose the colors. Get used to long format when using `ggplot`, it is more convenient and powerfull